# CSS position different in Chrome, IE, and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have a small image/arrow that appears under my menu items on hover. The problem is that IE and Firefox position the image differently than Chrome does. What is the problem and how might I fix this?

Here is my applied css:

```
img#menu-item-25{position:absolute;right:600px;top:92px;}
img#menu-item-26{position:absolute;right:510px;top:92px;}
img#menu-item-27{position:absolute;right:390px;top:92px;}
img#menu-item-30{position:absolute;right:220px;top:92px;}
img#menu-item-29{position:absolute;right:105px;top:92px;}
img#menu-item-28{position:absolute;right:15px;top:92px;}
```

Comment: By how much is the Firefox/IE rendering different from the Chrome rendering? I ask because the Chrome user agent stylesheet imposes an 8 pixel margin on the `body` element unless you override it, which might explain a small difference.

Comment: Can you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the example that is misbehaving?  I'd like to see it in action as I'm questioning why absolute positioning is being used.

Comment: Can we get an image and perhaps the HTML code that implements the CSS? Thanks!

Comment: There's a problem with providing a jsFiddle in this case - jsFiddle uses a CSS reset, and it's likely that the problem will not occur with a reset.

Comment: @sumo I know it's not standard to provide the url, but here it is, since i can't get a workin jsfiddle. http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars I have overridden any margin on the body